# UISwipeGestureRecognizer executes in an if/else statement when it should not

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, sprite-kit

I am attempting to run an action in iOS 7 Sprite Kit when the user swipes the left half of the screen.

To accomplish this I created a for loop waiting for touch events and, on touch, there is an if statement that checks to see if the touch location is less than half of the view's bounds.  The if statement itself is executing properly (the else half returns the proper NSLog if the touch is initiated on the right half of the screen).  The action triggered by the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, however, is called regardless of where the touch is initiated.  I have included a code sample below.

Is there is a reason this is not working as expected?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Touch location: %f, %f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);

    if (touchLocation.x<self.view.bounds.size.width/2) {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(self) action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
        swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeRight)];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(self) action:@selector(screenSwipedLeft)];
        swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeLeft)];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(self) action:@selector(screenSwipedUp)];
        swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeUp.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeUp)];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Touches were on the right!");
    }
}
}


-(void)screenSwipedRight
{
    CGFloat percentToRight = 1-(self.playerOne.position.x / self.view.bounds.size.width);
    NSTimeInterval timeToRight = self.horizontalRunSpeed * percentToRight;
    NSLog(@"Percent to right = %f",percentToRight);
    NSLog(@"Time to right = %f",timeToRight);
    SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveToX:self.view.bounds.size.width-self.playerOne.size.width duration:timeToRight];
    [self.playerOne runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveNodeRight]]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there is a reason this is not working as expected?

Yes.  You are adding a new set of swipe gesture recognizers any time any touch begins on the left half of the screen.  You are never removing them.  You are never restricting the conditions for the gesture recognizer to begin.

This should fix your issue:

1. Delete your implementation of `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.
2. Add your gesture recognizers in `viewDidLoad`.
3. Set `delegate = self` for all of the gesture recognizers.
4. Add this code:

   ```
   - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
       CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
       NSLog(@"Touch location: %f, %f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
       BOOL shouldBegin = (touchLocation.x < self.view.bounds.size.width / 2);
       return shouldBegin;
   }
   ```

Comment: The "action" being triggered is the selector at the end of the first line of each gesture recognizer.  The example included in the code sample is "screenSwipedRight".  If I move the gesture recognizers to viewdidload (view controller) will I be able to call a method from MyScene.m?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to scroll right.  Rookie mistake.  Yes, just change the "target" from `self` to your instance of MyScene.

Comment: And when your scene changes, you can use `addTarget:action:` and `removeTarget:action:` to update which scene should know about it, or even to notify multiple scenes.  When using remove, passing nil for target matches all targets and passing NULL for action matches all actions.

Comment: Wow you're awesome.  Thanks for taking the time to help.  I'm getting an error but I think I am on the right track.  After moving everything to ViewWillLayoutSubviews in the view controller and switching initWithTarget to MyScene I am seeing "Use of undeclared identifier 'action'"

Comment: I wouldn't create the gesture recognizers in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, since that will get called if the status bar size changes or the view rotates.  So you might end up with lots of copies of the same ones.

Comment: Good advice.  Moved to viewDidLoad.  I am still receiving the "Use of undeclared identifer 'action'" error though.

Comment: I would post that as a separate question, since it likely has to do with creating a MyScene object, and not to do with swipe gesture recognizers / touch events.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for all of your help with this.  My real goal here is to learn more about Objective C and you definitely helped move me further along.